# What Australian dishes - Aboriginal or otherwise - made of kangaroo meat should I not miss?

Tags: australia, food-and-drink

I've eaten kangaroo steak once (in Cambodia). Are there any traditional Australian dishes - Aboriginal in origin or otherwise - exist that use kangaroo meat, and is it easy to find them in restaurants?

Comment: related, but not direct dupe: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4280/101

Comment: Aborigine is the noun, aboriginal is the adjective. I'm going to reword your question since as it stands it looks you're talking about dishes made of aborigine! (-;

Comment: Traditional foods as eaten before the arrival of Europeans in Australia are now known as "bush tucker". On Wikipedia there is an article on it where they also call it ["bushfood"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bushfood).

Comment: Are you after meals that are traditionally associated with kangaroo meat, or merely meals that happen to use kangaroo meat? I'm no foodie, but I doubt the former exist. Non-indigenous Australians (at least those living in the major cities) have only recently started using kangaroo meat in a major way.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: Either, really. I haven't found any answers yet in the former category.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh have I got the page for you...

### [Kangaroo Meat Recipes](http://www.kangaroomeat.net.au/php/recipes.php)

- [Gluten Free Kanga Bangas (sausages)](http://www.kangaroomeat.net.au/php/recipe.php?id=1)

[image]

---

- [Kangaroo Burger](http://www.kangaroomeat.net.au/php/recipe.php?id=2)

[image]

---

- [Spaghetti and Kangaroo Meatballs](http://www.kangaroomeat.net.au/php/recipe.php?id=3)

[image]

---

- [Spiced Kangaroo Kebabs](http://www.kangaroomeat.net.au/php/recipe.php?id=4)

[image]

---

- [Marinated Kangaroo Fillets](http://www.kangaroomeat.net.au/php/recipe.php?id=5)

[image]

---

- [Kangaroo Fillets and Mash](http://www.kangaroomeat.net.au/php/recipe.php?id=6)

[image]

---

- [Kangaroo Cashew Stirfry](http://www.kangaroomeat.net.au/php/recipe.php?id=7)

[image]

---

Comment: Isn't there anything Aborigine or do they not eat kangaroos?

Comment: They do / did eat it, but I can't find a recipe as such - they call it *kere aherre* and really just cooked it on a bush fire.  So I suppose there's nothing stopping you doing that, aside from fire regulations...or if you can find a restaurant cooking outdoors for that smokey flavour...

Comment: Oh how I love posts with photos, especially when they're so appetizing!

Comment: Before white settlers arrived in Australia there were over 200 indigenous languages in Australia - there are still dozens left. This makes it somewhat meaningless to say what "aborigines" call any particular thing as there will be many different words across the country. Indigenous languages usually had different words for different kinds of kangaroo that English doesn't distinguish too.

Comment: fair enough, you're the one with the local knowledge, I was just using wikipedia for that bit ;)