# Eating cat meat as a tourist in Switzerland

Tags: legal, food-and-drink, switzerland, restaurants, pets

I've read that cat meat is eaten in Switzerland.

[Stop eating cats and dogs say animal rights campaigners in Switzerland](http://www.bbc.co.uk/newsbeat/30205410) cites an animal rights activist saying that it's not legal to sell cat meat (presumably it's talking about uncooked meat), but it's legal to eat your own.

Are there restaurants in Switzerland where I could still eat cat meat? Examples appreciated.

Comment: @MeNoTalk you upvoted http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/22137/324 . Also, there's a lot of other questions on this stack exchange about the eating of specific dishes, or meals involving particular meats - did you vote to close them?

Comment: It's definitively quite uncommon in Switzerland and you won't find it in any restaurant. Your best chance is probably when you try to get invited for dinner by a local farmer family in Appenzell. It's quite a open secret that they sometimes eat dogs, and very rarely probably also cats. Other than that, I see no options to get cat meat in Switzerland.

Comment: So somewhere in the east of Switzerland? (-:

Comment: [Alps, Edelweiss and... cat meat? What you apparently don't know about the Swiss](http://www.sbs.com.au/news/article/2014/11/26/alps-edelweiss-and-cat-meat-what-you-apparently-dont-know-about-swiss): "Hundreds of thousands of Swiss eat cats and dogs, according to an animal rights group that has demanded the government make it illegal for man to bite dog."

Comment: I had to slightly correct my comment from above. Your best chance is probably Ticino.

Comment: Being swiss, having lived here all my life and even growing up in a, especially compared to more populated countries, veeeery rural area, I haven't eaten either cat or dog. I also don't know anybody who eats either cat or dog. My grandmother used to tell stories of her childhood(!) about a group of neighbours who claimed to eat cat once in a while. I'm willing to bet it's a far more uncommon phenomenon than claimed in the articles posted here.

Comment: I am disturbed that this question is tagged [tag:pets]. You don't generally eat your pets!

Comment: @Thomas that tag was added by HippieTrail.

Comment: @Thomas Well, maybe someone else's ;)

Comment: @Thomas: Perhaps you don't, but I doubt that would hold as a general rule. In Germany, it is both common to hold rabbits as pets and to eat rabbit meat. It is also becoming increasingly popular to keep pigs as pets.

Comment: You can always go for `Chatzezöngli`, which translates to tongue of a cat... (http://www.coopathome.ch/b2c/start/%28carea=4AD5101ABD564590E10000000A030109&citem=3474606&xcm=coop_dev&cpgsize=24%29/.do)^^

Comment: @Thomas: Not even when they're in an [aquarium](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2332090/The-DIY-ecosystem-lets-grow-fresh-fish-living-room-eat-dinner-perfect-lazy-aquarium-owners.html)?

Comment: [Do 3% of the Swiss eat dogs and cats?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/23915/22115)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's not legal to sell cat meat in Switzerland, neither raw nor cooked. The Swiss [Regulation of the Confederate Department of Interior on food of animal origin, article 2](http://www.admin.ch/opc/de/classified-compilation/20050164/index.html#a2) has a list of animals of which the meat can be sold or distributed as food. It is therefore unlikely that you will find a restaurant catering with cat meat. If there are any, they are at least unlikely to advertise it.

What *is* allowed in Switzerland, is to slaughter and consume both cat and dog meat in a private setting. I am however keen to believe that the legal situation is similar in most other European countries. Even if commercial dsitribution is prohibited, I doubt that there are laws or regulations in many countries actually prohibiting consuming cat and dog meat.

Comment: Actually, there are. In Poland (and I suppose, in EU in general) killing animals on will is forbidden and treaten as animal cruelty. Animals can be killed in regulated ways, for example by vet or in slaughterhouse, and as there are no regulations for slaughter of dogs and cats, slaughtering them is illegal. There were show processes against traditional profession of dog grease producers.

Comment: There are AFAIK no EU regulations on this subject and you must differentiate between slaughtering, consuming and commercial distribution of the meat. The German Wikipedia article on cat meat summarizes the legal situation in Germany, Switzerland and Austria. In Germany and Switzerland, commercial distribution is prohibited. In Austria it is not allowed to slaughter cats and dogs for the purpose of obtaining food. Unless I miss something, this means that *consuming* cat meat is allowed in all three countries.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose eating dead animals (for example, killed in road accidents) is generally allowed. If you can't kill and can't import, there's no other source to legally get the meat. I can't say for Germany, I know in Poland there was the process for killing dogs (not selling their meat).

Comment: Just to add up on this answer. I was growing up in Luzern (one of the places named in the article) and I never heard of anybody eating cat/dog, except the normal urban legend stuff. But there are collecting signatures to prohibit it (http://www.soschats.org/) that's why there is some media attention lately.

Comment: @magu_: Maybe it'll be interesting to put the articles and petition to some scrutiny on skeptics.SE?

Comment: @hippietrail Someone already had that idea and wrote a question over there.

Comment: **[Do 3% of the Swiss eat dogs and cats?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/23915)**

Comment: @hippietrail, I also commented on it there.

Comment: Do you happen to know whether couchsurfing-like arrangements with strangers (where you live inside someone else's flat and thus might arrange to take part in meals) count as a "private setting"? i.e. would it be legal to take part in a cat/dog meal like that, or would that be seen as an illegal attempt at circumventing the arbitrary laws that allow to commercially get cow and pig meat, but not cat and dog meat? Incomprehensible as those restrictions may seem, I think their exact boundary is relevant to travelers interested in the topic of this question and could be added to this +1 answer.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I don't know. In Germany, services like couch-surfing and especially short-time appartment rentals (e.g. through airbnb) are in a legal grey area and regularly subject to discussions wether or not they are to be considered to be commercial lodging services. Not so much to find out if they can offer cat stew, but to clarify if people offering such services are subject to all other regulations and tax duties, which normally apply to commercial lodging services.