# What is this "nekoya" shop advertising?

Tags: japan, identify-this, tokyo

[image: Described below]

Image source: http://tokyo-oasis.blog.so-net.ne.jp/2009-10-13, used without permission

I've seen on twitter a photo of a cat carrying a shamisen, with the text ねこや ("nekoya", literally "cat shop"). There's a phone number underneath of (351) 1647. The store's address is 3-6-4, yotsuya, shinjuku-ku, Tokyo ([source](http://tokyotabibito.com/shop/nekoya/))

What is the shop selling? Is it selling shamisens (as [apparently claimed here](http://dankai-hiroba.cocolog-nifty.com/blog/2011/10/post-ed60.html)) which are traditionally made using cats, a cat cafe, or something else?

Comment: You do realise that the second link you gave clearly says it's a Shamisen store, yes?

Comment: @fkraiem Yes, but it didn't provide any evidence of that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, [the shop sells shamisen](http://makimino.jugem.jp/?eid=216) (a type of [musical instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamisen)), and yes, good-quality shamisen are still made using [cat skin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamisen#Construction).

Comment: I ran to google, searching for shamisen, expecting to see some dried cat meat or something. I am glad it is just a musical instrument.

Comment: @Heidel [that'd be Switzerland](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39096/eating-cat-meat-as-a-tourist-in-switzerland).